# How to upload a image/file to cosmos db using mongodb api?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

**I would like to upload a file from html form using an api written in node js. 
Following code is the api to upload the file ,But i am not able to get the exact query for saving a file as attachment in the db.**

```
server.post('/upload/', passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', {
    session: false
}), (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.body.userId ||  !req.body._id ) {
        return res.send({"message":"missingParameter","statuscode":"404"});

    }
    else {





        // // Retrieve
        var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
        // Connect to the db
        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", function(err,client) {
            var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = client.db("Db");



        }
    }
}
```

//below is the query to insert data .How to insert a file using mongodb query into cosmos db.

```
          var data = { "_id" : ObjectId(req.body._id) ,"file":req.body.files};


          dbo.collection("uploads").insert(data, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("1 document inserted");
            client.close();
            return res.send({"message":"success"});
          });
        //

    });


}
```

});

Comment: You should not use CosmosDB for file storage. It is not meant to be used as a file storage database. That's why there is a 2MB limitation per document. You should be using something like Azure Blog Storage for that.

Comment: hi @NickChapsas My files are less than 2 MB  can you please help me to store the files in cosmos using mongodb api

Comment: @NickChapsas is correct, although he means [Azure BLOB storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/).